# AngularJS handling data outside ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Inside my AngularJS app index.html page I have three main divs (top, footer and ) which display different views depending on current route. The problem I am facing now is that I need to display some data in the footer area, including data that will require loop (ex. list of States, Cities...etc) but I am not sure how to display data in index.html outside of the ng-view. So can someone tell me how this can be accomplished? Any example code is highly appreciated. Thanks

Below is my index.html structure, App.js

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', 
  {     templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', 
        controller: 'HController',
        title: 'Home',

  });

}]);
```

Index.html

```
  <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>...</head>
  <div id="header">....</div>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <div id="header">
     <!-- Here is where I need to loop to display data -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ngRoute` and `ng-view` does not preclude using `ng-controller` and other angular constructs in your code as long as the code resides inside an element which has `ng-app` attribute (or has been [`bootstrapped`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)).

So, since you have `ng-app` attribute on `html`, you can define a new controller and use it in `#header`:

**index.html:**

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="headerController">
   {{myData}}
   <!-- Here is where I need to loop to display data -->
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
myApp.controller('headerController', 
    [ '$scope', function ($scope) { 
        $scope.myData = 'Stuff.'; 
    }]
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and example, highly appreciated. One last question, I've read AngularJS documentation regarding Controllers but never came across this piece of information, so may I ask where did you know it? I mean where in AngularJS documentation this information is listed? Thanks

Comment: @MChan [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) you can see an example of it, it uses ng-view and above that they declare an ng-controller to display route information.

Comment: @MChan Technically, this information is on the main page: [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org/), in the second example. :) The first thing I would have noticed is that `ngRoute` is an external package and, hence, there must be a way of using angular without `ngRoute`. Then, once it is known that a solution must exist, it is merely a matter of connecting the dots together.

Comment: @musically_ut I just checked angularjs.org and I can't seem to see an example that use ng-view and another controller on same html, can you please point me which example exactly you are referring to?

Comment: @MChan There are some _core_ parts of angular (like `controllers` and `directives`) and then there are _addons_ (like `routeProvider`, and `ngAnimate`). The second example shows how to use bare `controller`s in Angular code without any bells or whistles. `routeProvider` is an ancillary feature to merely link one directive's behavior (`ngView`) and its `scope` (using a controller) to changes in the URL.